# Dropdown menu going underneath certain elements in Internet Explorer 7/8

Tags: css

A site I am developing is giving me some serious issues in Internet Explorer 7/8.  On certain pages, the navigation goes underneath text and images.  I'm rather confused.  I've tried adding a z-index of 1 to the content and a higher Z-index to the navigation, but it is to no avail.

The link to the site with the problem and respective CSS file:

http://exitbellaire.com/exit-air.php

The CSS file is `/style.css`.

Comment: Can you be more explicit in what problems you are seeing?  I see nothing untoward on FF, IE8 (not in IE7 compatability mode) or IE7.

Comment: On IE hover over the link for Listings and the lower half of the popup menu likes to display itself under the pictures at the bottom.  It is happening intermittently for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it. I removed a `position:relative` tag from a div and things started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add the higher z-index attribute to the .sf-menu and other #navigation element CSS as well, in addition to the base navigation div.

Answer (score 0):

Z-index doesn't have any effect on a normally-positioned element. Try adding "position: relative" to the items you've put a z-index on, one at a time, and see if there's any change. Older versions of IE have a bad habit of looking at parent z-indicies, so that while something might have a z-index of 10, if its parent has a z-index of 1, the 10 will not show up over other elements with lower z-indicies.

Comment: Ah well, glad you fixed it and your post about z layer contexts makes more sense than my perception about parent elements. "More sense" in the lowest sense, not that I like MS' approach.

Comment: indeed...  IE takes up about 97% of my "css fixing" time :/